# Detectinig the target of the click using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, contextmenu, dhtml, right-click

How do I detect what object or ID or the user right-clicked on? I'm using the onContextMenu to trigger a function but I don't know how to detect the target.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (document.addEventListener) {
        document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
            alert(e.target.nodeName); //or e.target.getAttribute('id') 
            e.preventDefault();
        }, false);
    } else {
        document.attachEvent('oncontextmenu', function(e) {
            alert(window.event.srcElement.nodeName); //or e.srcElement and then like above
            window.event.returnValue = false;
        });
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<span>Lorem ipsum...</span><br/>
body content
</body>
</html>
```

PS. I've seen similar code before ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your handler should accept an event object as its parameter; the srcElement property of the event will be the object that triggered the event.

Answer (score 0):

As **Patrick** mentioned, you are receiving an event object as parameter to your onContentMenu callback function, where you can find the element triggered the event. I am using this code for cross-browser compatibility.

```
var oE = event.srcElement || event.originalTarget;
```

Note: originalTarget is Mozilla specific. You might want to pay attention to event.target https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.target